# Rails app dies. No stack trace, just hitting a 500 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

My app loads multiple partials for each row I need within the activity_set partial. It's taking about 30 seconds, my app throws a "We're sorry, but something went wrong." 500 error I assume, but unicorn.log doesn't show anything and neither does my production.log. I'm blind for the first time...

I, [2014-05-22T01:38:19.938799 #22221]  INFO -- :   Rendered registrations/_activity_row.html.erb (4.6ms)
I, [2014-05-22T01:38:20.347306 #22221]  INFO -- :   Rendered registrations/_activity_row.html.erb (4.5ms)
I, [2014-05-22T01:38:20.622309 #22221]  INFO -- :   Rendered registrations/_activity_row.html.erb (5.4ms)
I, [2014-05-22T01:38:20.674423 #22221]  INFO -- :   Rendered registrations/_activity_row.html.erb (5.2ms)
I, [2014-05-22T01:38:21.073015 #22221]  INFO -- :   Rendered registrations/_activity_set.html.erb (29767.5ms)

Comment: Can you add the relevant pieces of code based on this log output, i.e. the action and including this partial?

Comment: Where is this hosted and how long is "a long time"? If it's Heroku and > 30 seconds, then you're just hitting Heroku's timeout. You'll need to optimize this to take less time.

Comment: From the posted log, it indeed seems to hit a 30s timeout, rendering _activity_set.html.erb took 29767.5ms. If you've got a large amount of elements to show, consider using pagination, and make sure there's no N+1 queries.

Comment: I'll give a bit more information on the server. When the page loads, the CPU hits 100%. We added a second cpu and the load went to 50% and gave the same scenario. So now I'm wondering how I can tell my VPS to use 2 processors instead of just one...

Comment: @fivedigit The rows that I'm showing are complex rows from a table of choices that must all be displayed. I can't paginate the rows.

Comment: @ryan-ahearn about 30 seconds before it craps out.

Comment: @vee the partial uses many database calls (through model helpers) to piece together all the data needed for the row. So I'm hitting the database a lot. The server has app, web and db on it. So I've recommended that we go to the 3 server architecture as a first measure.

Answer (score 0):

Though I didn't find out why it was running off with my CPU, I ended up refactoring the code. I was iterating within an iteration. Fine for 10 records, not so fine for 50 records. 50 x 50 ain't pretty. Definitely hit a limitation in rails. Thanks for helping me though. Back into the fold I go...